# Does $E$($X$) = $E$($Y$) implies that $P$($X$=$Y$) = $1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So let $X$,  $Y$ be discrete random variables.

I think that the following statement is wrong:

$E$($X$) = $E$($Y$) implies that $P$($X$ = $Y$) = $1$ .
( $E$($X$) is the expected value )

I'm pretty sure there is counterexample. But i failed.

Comment: You can roll two fair six sided die, namely X and Y. Does $P(X=Y)=1$ hold?

Comment: Does $E(X)=E(0)$ imply that $P(X=0)=1$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $X$  with $P(X = -1) = P(X = 1) = 1/2$ so $E[X] = 0$. On the other hand, let $Y$ be such that $P(Y = 0) = 1$. We have $E[Y] = E[X]$ but they are clearly not the same; in fact $P(X \neq Y) = 1$.